# Speeding up reading JPEG2000 images using Python

Tags: python, matlab, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I am trying to read JPEG2000 images which are roughly 86kB (size = (4096,21504))  using Python. I used `skimage` and `pillow` modules to read them. The time it takes to read either of these files is ~1s.

Here are snippets on how I read the images.

**`SKIMAGE`**

```
im = io.imread(filename,plugin='freeimage')
```

**`PILLOW`**

```
im = Image.open(filename)
```

Using profiling I can see that the JPEG2000 decoder is responsible for the slowdown.

On the other hand, reading the same image using MATLAB's imread takes ~0.5s.

Is it possible to speed up the reading of JPEG2000 using Python libraries? Are there other libraries that could speed decoding process? I tried searching for ways to speed it up and couldn't find anything on this. I would appreciate links/reports that will point me to the right direction.

---

**Computer Specs**

- OS: Windows 8.1
- Processor: Intel i7-4930K@3.40GHz
- RAM: 32.0 GB

Comment: Most packages make use of libopenjpeg.  The only Python package I can think of that uses anything else is OpenCV, which builds on top of libjasper.

Comment: Thank you @StefanvanderWalt van der Walt. I made the OpenCV package as per the instructions online and included the libjasper package as well. I then copied all the .lib files to the **libs** folder in Python. I included all the 3rd party library files as well. Now, when I attempt to read the image it returns None. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Do I need to add any specific flags to read JPEG images?

Comment: Sorry, I have never used opencv for this myself, and I see the same behavior you do.